# locate behavior with bash wildcards

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have

```
$ ls -l re*trict
ls: cannot access re*trict: No such file or directory
```

Why does this give 0 matches?

```
$ locate -c 're*trict'
0
$ locate -c re*trict
0
$ locate -c re?trict
0
```

This works though and gives 8351 matches:

```
$ locate -c restrict
8351
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`locate` matches against the full path name. To find `re*trict` as a substring, you have to add `*` before and after it:

```
locate '*re*trict*'
```

Comment: `locate restrict` lists paths where `restrict` appears as a substring.

Comment: "If any  `PATTERN`  contains  no  globbing  characters, locate behaves as if the pattern were `*PATTERN*`." (man locate)

Comment: And if PATTERN does contain globbing characters then it tries to find a literal exact match against the full path name...right?

Comment: Yes. (more chars to allow posting)

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is available on the man page:

*If any PATTERN contains no glob‐bing characters, locate behaves as if the pattern were *PATTERN*.*

Since my PATTERN contains a globbing character it is not expanded to *PATTERN* and so a literal match is tried to be found. Obviously there is no file with name (substituting s) `'restrict'` since even under root the name of such file would be `/re?trict` and the match would fail because of a leading `/`