# locate j*.vim doesn't work?

Tags: locate

I've read the locate man page and searched this site, but I don't see how to do this:

I'm looking for all *.vim files starting with j. How can I use locate to achieve this?

```
[docker@docker1 ~]$ locate java.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/java.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/java.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/java.vim

[docker@docker1 ~]$ locate "j*.vim"
[docker@docker1 ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `find` command.
Just type `find -name "j*.vim"` and you will get expected search result.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150238/locate-behavior-with-bash-wildcards), and it's simple. Locate stores the whole path, so you need a wildcard on BOTH sides on your search terms:

```
docker@docker1:~$ locate '*jav*.vim'
/usr/share/vim/vim74/autoload/javascriptcomplete.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/compiler/javac.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/java.vim
```

You can, of course, also resort to regular expressions:

```
docker@docker1:~$ locate -r 'jav.*.vim'
/usr/share/vim/vim74/autoload/javascriptcomplete.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/compiler/javac.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/java.vim
```